# How to integrate the Flash Player installation with multiple browsers on a given computer?

Tags: installation, browser, flash-player, swf

After installing Flash10 player; the installer integrated it into IE (which was where I'd started from).

I assumed it would also have been integrated into my Seamonkey, and Chrome browsers.

Not only is this assumption false; attempts to install it explicitly also fail with a message to the effect that the browser is in use, and therefore conflicts with the installer. This is confusing because I rarely use more than one browser at a time, and even less rare that both browsers be pointed to a site with an SWF running.

How to integrate the Flash Player installation with multiple browsers on a given computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flash player for IE is an ActiveX control, which is not the preferred format for plugins for Mozilla et al.  The later versions of Chrome already include Flash (from version [5.0.375 onwards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Release_history), with the exception of the 64-bit Chromium for Linux, though I don't know if that's changed)), so you don't have to worry about updating the plugin.  That leaves Seamonkey.  You will probably have to go to the [website](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) which will install it for you.

Unfortunately, your browser doesn't have to be playing a swf at the time.  Just having it open conflicts with the installer.  Restarting should clear any components that are running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different Adobe flash players.  One is for IE only.  The other is for all other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc.).  You can find them on filehippo.com or majorgeeks.com.  There is also an uninstaller that gets rid of all old flash players.  I suggest downloading and saving the uninstaller and the two flash players.  Run the uninstaller; restart your computer; run the two flash player installers.  I do this every time there are new flash players and I have never had any problems.